# Is there a secret fake Mongolian Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, languages

From a tweet:

> @[redacted] @[also redacted] Mongolian is the "fake" language we use when localizing #stackoverflow #trivia

Is there an actual fake Mongolian Stack Overflow where you play around with localisation? Or is it just a placeholder in conversations, like "Does Similar Questions get localised in the Mongolian Stack Overflow?"?

If it exists, does it use [Mongolian Cyrillic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongolian_Cyrillic_alphabet), or [Mongolian script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongolian_script), which is a vertical script?

Comment: I always assumed if was [MoonSpeak](https://dev.stackoverflow.com), as you can select that in the dropdown in the footer...

Comment: Isn't referring to Mongolian as a 'fake' language ... ahem, slightly politically incorrect?

Comment: Might be a fair point @DeerHunter I guess *fake* should be in quotes everywhere ...

Comment: @DeerHunter oh no! I knew Kazakhstan was fictional, but I didn't know neighbouring Mongolia was as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We are using the Mongolian locale code, [mn-MN](http://www.localeplanet.com/dotnet/mn-MN/index.html) internally (local and dev builds) for ease of localization.

It was chosen as it kinda looks like it is the locale code for MoonSpeak, our codename for localization.

Instead of actually localizing strings, we just replace characters with other Unicode characters, so when a page loads, if something is still in English, it has not been localized - makes it easy to identify strings that have not been localized yet. In that respect it is a fake Mongolian language - it isn't actual Mongolian, even though we do use that locale code.